# Generate new id column based off other ids in different column

Tags: r

This might seem a little trivial but I'm trying to generate ids based off ids in another column. However, the new ids should be built based on a formula and should increment `1:5` for every id in the first column.

So something like this:

```
list_ids_2 <- tibble(id = rep(c(12345, 34564, 234521, 90889), each = 5))

# For each id in `list_ids_2` there should be 5 ids 
# with this formula (100*(id + 1200) + j), 
# where j starts at 1 and increases until 5 
# at which point it moves to the next id and does the #same thing again.

#This works only in the sense that it produces 20 new ids. Ideally though, the initial ids #(above) wouldn't already have to be replicated 5 times.

list_ids_2$new_id <- 0

for (i in unique(list_ids_2$id)) {
  #print(i)
  
  for (j in 1:5){
    
    #print(j)
    
    b <- (( 100 * (i + 1200) + j))
    
    print(b)
    
    #list_ids_2$new_id[1,1] <- b
  }
}

[1] 124234501
[1] 124234502
[1] 124234503
[1] 124234504
[1] 124234505
[1] 126456401
[1] 126456402
[1] 126456403
[1] 126456404
[1] 126456405
[1] 146452101
[1] 146452102
[1] 146452103
[1] 146452104
[1] 146452105
[1] 132088901
[1] 132088902
[1] 132088903
[1] 132088904
[1] 132088905
#Adding this to the list_ids_2 tibble doesn't work though.
```

This also works so-so, but does not increment the numbers `1:5`

```
generator <- function(x){
  
  j <-  1
  
  while(j <= 5){
    
    b <- (( 100 * (x + 1200) + j))
    
    j <-  j + 1
    
    return(b)
    print(b)
    
  }
  
}

generator(c(1234,1234))
[1] 123123401 123123401
```

Ideally, I'd start with a data-frame, and probably have to end up with a new data-frame/tibble b/c of dimensionality, which is why the result can't just be added to the list_ids_2 tibble.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give a sample of what the desired output would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer` or `sapply` with `+`:

```
id = c(12345, 34564, 234521, 90889)

outer(id, 1:5, "+")
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
# [1,]  12346  12347  12348  12349  12350
# [2,]  34565  34566  34567  34568  34569
# [3,] 234522 234523 234524 234525 234526
# [4,]  90890  90891  90892  90893  90894

sapply(id, "+", 1:5)
#       [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] 12346 34565 234522 90890
# [2,] 12347 34566 234523 90891
# [3,] 12348 34567 234524 90892
# [4,] 12349 34568 234525 90893
# [5,] 12350 34569 234526 90894
```

In both cases you get a `matrix` result. Use `c()` or `as.vector()` on it to turn it into a regular vector.

In either case you can use `100 * (id + 1200)` as the first input instead of the untransformed `id`.

Putting those pieces together:

```
c(sapply(100 * (id + 1200), "+", 1:5))
#  [1]  1354501  1354502  1354503  1354504  1354505  3576401
#  [7]  3576402  3576403  3576404  3576405 23572101 23572102
# [13] 23572103 23572104 23572105  9208901  9208902  9208903
# [19]  9208904  9208905
```

Here's a couple `tidyverse` adaptations:

```
# starting with repeated IDs
list_ids_2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(idx = 100 * (id + 1200) + row_number())


# starting with unique IDs
uid = unique(list_ids_2)
uid %>%
  mutate(idx = map(100 * (id + 1200), ~ . + 1:5)) %>%
  unnest(idx)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll give this a shot. Do you know if this would also work with `map` in a tidyverse setting?

Comment: Sure, `map(id, ~ . + 1:5)` works too, though it returns a `list()`.

Comment: Added a couple quick tidyverse methods

Comment: Oh awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using purrr `map2()` could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_ids_2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(j = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(idx = unlist(map2(id, j,  ~ 100*(.x + 1200) + .y))) %>%
  select(-j)

#       id      idx
#    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  12345  1354501
# 2  12345  1354502
# 3  12345  1354503
# 4  12345  1354504
# 5  12345  1354505
# 6  34564  3576401
# 7  34564  3576402
# 8  34564  3576403
# 9  34564  3576404
# 10 34564  3576405
```